# why this synchronized method is not working as expected?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized, scjp

Could someone explain two me why these to codes dont output the same results (the only difference between two codes is in the run() method) ?

NB: the first code seems not doing any lock!

**First Code:**

```
class LetterThread extends Thread 
{

    private StringBuffer letter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer sbltr = new StringBuffer("A");

        LetterThread one = new LetterThread(sbltr);
        LetterThread two = new LetterThread(sbltr);
        LetterThread three = new LetterThread(sbltr);

        one.setName("Thread ONE");
        two.setName("Thread TWO");
        three.setName("Thread THREE");

        one.start();
        two.start();
        three.start();

    }

    LetterThread(StringBuffer letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " (" + x
                        + ") = " + letter);
            }

            letter.setCharAt(0, (char) (letter.charAt(0) + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

**Second Code:** this code is working exactely as expecting to

```
class LetterThread extends Thread 
{

    private StringBuffer letter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer sbltr = new StringBuffer("A");

        LetterThread one = new LetterThread(sbltr);
        LetterThread two = new LetterThread(sbltr);
        LetterThread three = new LetterThread(sbltr);

        one.setName("Thread ONE");
        two.setName("Thread TWO");
        three.setName("Thread THREE");

        one.start();
        two.start();
        three.start();

    }

    LetterThread(StringBuffer letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (letter) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " (" + x
                        + ") = " + letter);
            }

            letter.setCharAt(0, (char) (letter.charAt(0) + 1));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Code**

The thing is that you have 3 instances of a thread and each threads runs it's own `synchronized` instance of the method `run()`. But there is always only one thread that is wating to be synchronized to it's own `run()` method, so it will run whenever the threads wants it to run. This results in no synchronization at all.

**Second Code**

You have also 3 instances of a thread, but they *share a reference* to the letter object. Therefore if you lock this reference, the threads will exclude each other and the code runs as expected.

**Additional Information**

This post explains pretty good why the first solution doesn't work: [Should you synchronize the run method? Why or why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313657/should-you-synchronize-the-run-method-why-or-why-not)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to synchronize two threads you must lock on a shared resource by all threads. Synchronizing in the run method(or any instance method in thread class) each thread locks it's own method resulting no synchronization at all.

Comment: Re "each thread locks its own method"  You can't lock a method.  When you write `synchronized void run() {...}` you are locking `this`.  Otherwise you are correct:  `synchronized(letter)...` works because `letter` refers to the same object in all three threads.  `synchronized void run()...` doesn't work because `this` is different in each of the threads.

Comment: @jameslarge yeah that was i meant, my bad