# Why are my threads not executed one after another when I use 'synchronized'?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I use `synchronized` in order to execute first thread and then execute another when the first thread finished, but both threads are executed at the same time. Why?

```
public class PrintNums extends Thread {
    int num;

    public PrintNums(int x) {
        this.num = x;  
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.count();
    }

    public synchronized void count() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println((2 * i - this.num));
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintNums odd = new PrintNums(1);
        PrintNums even = new PrintNums(0);

        odd.start();
        even.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Synchronization is for access to a particular object (ie, synchronization to one object). You have two different objects (`odd` and `even`).

Comment: [why this synchronized method is not working as expected?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26610791)

Answer (score 2):

`synchronized` without an explicit target means `synchronized(this)`: Each thread is synchronizing on itself, so there's no conflict. If you want to serialize them, you could use `synchronized(PrintNums.class)`.

Note that there is usually a better construct generally than using explicit threads, such as an executor or a latch.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think I understand the reason now!